# EC2 Instance doesn't start after Reattaching the Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to lunch an instance from backup snapshots.
I follow the procedure [here](http://cloud.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/cloud-computing-l/how-do-you-start-an-ec2-instance-based-off-of-an-ebs-snapshot-3759966) :

1. Goto the snapshot section of the aws tools.
2. Create a volume from the snapshot.
3. Create an ec2 instance (make sure it's an EBS backed instance, if it's the same kind as the original snapshot you'll be fine)
4. Stop the instance
5. Detach the existing EBS volume from the instance
6. Attach the volume you just created, make sure you give it the same name as the instance that was attached.
7. Start the instance back up.

Not quite sure what is EBS backed instance.

Every thing works fine,But after I reattach the volume,The instance I created cant get start,when i press start,it pending for awhile then stopped again.
What maybe the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the Volume you are detaching [ is it root volume ? ].

Comment: @Naveen Yes I detached root..

Comment: Are you reattaching a volume which has boot specific information i.e. the volume which you are attaching must also be a root voulme or snapshot of existing root volume. Can you check on that ?

Comment: This is the second time you've posted the same question. Please edit your original question rather than posting a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [amazon ec2 instance can't login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153517/amazon-ec2-instance-cant-login)

Comment: @ScottMcGready its different,this is start instance. and the link is use auth method via ssh or sth to login server.

Answer (score 5):

I also have done this before. It works. When you reattach the volume check the name, it should be identical to the original root volume name. If the root volume name is different it can't start.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. It failed when I attached the root volume as `/dev/sda`. Reattaching it as `/dev/sda1` did the trick.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I tried both /dev/sda1 and /dev/xvda, and both didn't work...

Comment: This just worked for me. Assigning the previously detached volume back as `/dev/sda1` for a CentOS instance correctly attached it as root device. The modifications made to the device (increasing disk space) also took effect.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Basically the "Device" attachment information that is auto-populated wasn't right.

When I tried starting the EC2 instance the error read.

[image]

The error ,clearly states that volume isn't attached at(**/dev/xvda**)

Now, navigate back to volumes. Undo the previous attached volume.

Attach the volume again by providing the "Device" info as provided in the error message, /dev/xvda in this case.

Comment: AWS suggested xvdf but it is true as you say my error msg said ( /dev/sda1 ) I changed to that and it worked. (I guess why AWS suggest xvdf is just to confuse the russians :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Before detaching the volume, note down the volume id and device name which is actually mounted right now.

Then while reattaching another volume, you need to make above device name only otherwise it will not start.